# How can I adjust lines in a radar plot made with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I would like to make a radar graph in ggplot for the following data set:

```
Types Risk_Value
1 Resiliency Risk          1
2       Data Risk          2
3  Financial Risk          1
4       Tool Risk          1
5      Other Risk          1
```

My code so far:

```
plot = ggplot(data = RiskPlot, aes(x=substr(Types,1,1), y = Risk_Value, fill = Types)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
      theme_minimal()+
      theme( text = element_text(size = 35),
             panel.border = element_blank(),
             panel.background = element_blank(),
             axis.title = element_blank(),
             axis.text.y = element_blank(),
             legend.text=element_text(size=25),
             legend.position = "left") +
      coord_polar(start =0) +
      ylim(-1,3) +
      annotate(
        x = .5, 
        y = 1, 
        label = "Low", 
        geom = "text",
        size = 10
      ) +
      annotate(
        x = .5, 
        y = 3, 
        label = "High", 
        geom = "text",
        size = 10
      ) + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))
```

It produces this chart below:

[image: Sample chart]

I feel that I'm 99% there, but would love to change the following: (1) any way to remove the outmost ring, and (2) would it be possible to remove the lines in the middle with plain white (i.e. have the middle circle just be the background color)?

Any help would be appreciated,

Philipp

Comment: try adding `axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()` within theme(). Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RKeithL but unfortunately, that made no difference.

Comment: I'm far from an expert, @PMaier, but I do hope to help you. Given you're passing `theme_minimal()`, it could be that `axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()` are being overridden. I'd still try using those but drop `theme_minimal()`.

Comment: @RKeithL this removes _all_ lines; any way to just remove the outmost ring but keep the inner rings? (You're pointed me towards the right direction; I'll keep looking...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the gridlines entirely, and use annotations to draw only the desired lines. From a visualization point of view, it may be best to directly label the segments using `coord_curvedpolar` from geomtextpath, and keep the fill color to highlight the risk score.

Incidentally, this is *not* a radar plot. It is a polar bar plot.

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(RiskPlot, aes(Types, Risk_Value, fill = Risk_Value)) +
  geom_blank() +
  annotate("segment", x = 0.5 + 0:4, y = rep(0, 5), xend = 0.5 + 0:4,
           yend = rep(2, 5), colour = "gray", linewidth = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0, 1, 2), color = "gray", linewidth = 0.5) +
  geom_col(width = 1, col = "#ffffff80", linewidth = 0.5, alpha = 0.8) +
  coord_curvedpolar(start = 2*pi/10) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green4", high = "red3") +
  ylim(-1, 2) +
  annotate("text", x = c(5, 5), y = c(0.5, 1.5), 
           label = c("Low", "High"), size = 10) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme( text = element_text(size = 10 * .pt),
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         panel.background = element_blank(),
         axis.title = element_blank(),
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1),
         legend.position = "none",
         panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: This looks awesome! Thank you, Allan.

Comment: Allen - one follow-up question: I need the labels quite big (about size 20), which makes them exceed the canvas. I've experimented with plot.margin and panel.spacing to shrink the size of the plot and move the labels a bit "inward", but no luck. Any suggestions here?